# I can't get datagramSocket receive from IPv6

Tags: android, sockets, udp, ipv6

I am trying to used the datagramsocket so we used the following code :

```
  ds = new DatagramSocket(null);
  ds.setReuseAddress(true);
  ds.setSoTimeout(10000);
  ds.bind(new InetSocketAddress(UDP_PORT));
  DatagramPacket rp = new DatagramPacket(testPack, testPack.length, InetAddress.getByName("IPAddress"),UDP_PORT);
  ds.send(rp);

  while(true)
   {
     ds.receive(receivedPacket);
   }
```

I can get received packet when "IPAddress" is belong with IPv4 , but can't not work on IPv6!

I'm sure that "IPAddress" on IPv6 is correct ip because I can ping it!

is any problem in this code?

Comment: Does your Android device support IPv6?

Comment: I can find IPv6 address in Settings->Wi-Fi->Advanced ! is it meaning support IPv6?

Comment: The source code for IPv6 is true! The problem is my hardware's bug!

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the reason somehow. 
The ipv6 address used by your program may be wrong.
you can try:

`ds.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ipv6InetAddress,UDP_PORT));`